# How to type hint yielded variable in with...as... style context manager?

Tags: python, python-3.x, types

Consider a sample JSON file:

```
[
    {"name": "alex"},
    {"name": "roger"},
    {"name": "lily"},
    {"name": "billy"}
]
```

It is easy to interact with it from disk as follows:

```
import os
import json
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def documentDB(file_name):
    with open(file_name, mode='rt') as fp:
        cur = json.load(fp)
    yield cur
    with open(file_name, mode='wt') as fp:
        json.dump(cur, fp)
    return

# following code works nicely
with documentDB("sample.json") as dbCur:
    print(dbCur)
```

But how do I assert / hint that `dbCur` in above code should be a list of dict objects? I tried this:

```
from typing import List

# does not work
with documentDB("sample.json") as dbCur: List[dict]:
    print(dbCur)
```

but I get syntax error.

Comment: From [PEP 526 - Where annotations aren't allowed](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#where-annotations-aren-t-allowed): "In addition, one cannot annotate variables used in a for or with statement; they can be annotated ahead of time, in a similar manner to tuple unpacking:", e.g. `dbCur: List[dict]; with ... as dbCur:`

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what you are trying to achieve, but if the type hint is meant for an IDE then most of then will understand the following as a type hint for dbCur:

```
from typing import List

with documentDB("sample.json") as dbCur:  # type: List[dict]
    print(dbCur)
```